# Setting Request Property in DownloadManager request

Tags: android, download-manager

I have been using a `urlconnection` a background service to download files in my application. The request requires a token which should be passed to the server for permission to be granted. The code works fine. Here is a snippet..

```
           URL url = new URL(fileURL);

            HttpURLConnection conection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "USER_AGENT");
            conection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
            conection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Token " + token);// evince
            conection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
            conection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "identity");

            int responseCode = conection.getResponseCode();
```

Now I want to modify the download process to use android's DownloadManager, the problem is how do I set all these request properties in DownloadManager's request object just like the code snippet above. Because the download will continue to fail without these properties set.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I finally figured how to do this after researching.

```
        DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
        request.addRequestHeader("Authorization", "Token " + token);
        request.addRequestHeader("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
        request.addRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        request.addRequestHeader("Accept-Encoding", "identity");
        request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", "USER_AGENT");

        File direct = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Abeti");
        if (!direct.exists()) {
            direct.mkdirs();
        }

        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/Abeti", filenamex);
        request.setTitle(cw.getTitle());


        enqueue = downloadManager.enqueue(request);
```

Comment: request headers okay, but I want to add as body. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem with user-agent. This worked out for me:

```
DownloadManager dManager = (DownloadManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(fileUrl + "?sid=" + sessionId));

request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", System.getProperty("http.agent") + " myApp_app/" + Utils.appVersionNumber());

dManager.enqueue(request);
```